# React Native - Fitting elements precisely

Tags: ios, react-native, flexbox

Can anyone please explain this layout cunundrum to me / suggest a better approach please:

I have a dynamic array of images and a 'add photo' button which are layed out in equal widths in rows - i want the thumbnails / button to be eactly the same width / height and show in 3's across the block.  heres a pic -

[image]

heres the layout code:

```
  <View style={PhotoStyles.imgThumbnailWrap}>
            {this.state.ADImageArray.map((prop, key) => {

               return (
                 <View style={PhotoStyles.imgThumbnailBlock}>
                  <Image
                    source={{uri: prop, isStatic: true}}
                    style={PhotoStyles.imgThumbnail}
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.removephoto} style={PhotoStyles.removePhotoLnk}>
                      <Image
                        source={require('../images/icons/ico-removeImg.png')}
                        style={PhotoStyles.removePhotoImg}
                      />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
               );
            })}
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.photoAdditional} >
            <View style={PhotoStyles.imgThumbAddMore}>
              <Image source={require('../images/icons/ico-upload-photo.png')} style={PhotoStyles.imgThumbnailBtn} />
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
```

heres the relevant styles:
  const itemWidth = (Dimensions.get('window').width / 3) -30;

imgThumbnailBlock: {
        margin:8,
        width:itemWidth,
        height:itemWidth,
        position:'relative',
  },
  imgThumbnail: {
    backgroundColor:'#f79431',
    width:itemWidth,
    height:itemWidth,

```
},
```

imgThumbnailBtn: {

```
width:25,
height:25,
```

},
  imgThumbnailWrap: {
    flex:1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    flexWrap:'wrap',
    marginTop:15,
    marginBottom:15,
    marginLeft:15,
    marginRight:15,

},
  imgThumbAddMore: {
    width:itemWidth,
    height:itemWidth,
    margin:8,
      backgroundColor: '#e9e9e9',
      alignItems:'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',

},

as you can see the images container (imgThumbnailBlock:)and add more button container imgThumbAddMore have an applied width /height provided by the itemwidth calculation.
**const itemWidth = (Dimensions.get('window').width / 3) -30;**

My iphone has an available width of 375 - if i divide that by 3 for each item - take away the margin from each (I'd like a 10 margin) and minus the container padding of 30 divided by 3 for each item - that leaves the subtracted 30 from each width as above.  this provides a width of each block as 95 with the applied 10 margin and container padding this adds up to 375 - so everything should fit exactly.
But when i apply this the third item falls onto the second line.  I need to reduce the margin value to 8pm to allow everything to fit - this makes zero sense to me - can off a suggestion / explanation please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it should work like this, I setup an Expo Snack for you:

https://snack.expo.io/@moritzw1/image-grid-fitting

So I'm guessing there is something outside of your top level

`<View style={PhotoStyles.imgThumbnailWrap}>`

that causes the view to shrink (like borders, padding or margin).

Comment: thanks @mortizw.  I still dont understand where the extra pixels were coming from - so i basically scrapped and rebuilt they layout again following the above process and it works fine!  Cheers for your help..